# checkbox for Drupal CCK

Tags: drupal, checkbox, drupal-6, radio-button, cck

I'm new at Drupal. love it so far :)

I'm creating a CCK custom content type. I need to make a amenities list in checkbox format. so I made;

> File Type: **Text**
>
> Widget Type:
>   **checkboxes/radiobuttons**

and Allowed values list:

> onsite_dining|Onsite Dining
>
> meeting_space|Meeting Space
>
> business_center|Business Center

and it creates Radio Buttons which only 1 selection :( How can I make it Check Box to give ability to select more than 1?

Appreciate helps!

Comment: sorted! "Number of values:" supposed to be more than 1.

Comment: Haha saw your comment too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There as an option: **Number of values**
You have to set it to something other than one.
This option is below the **Required** checkbox in the field settings page.