# Adding multiple checkbox in drupal using cck

Tags: checkbox, drupal-7, boolean, content-type, cck

I am trying to add multiple checkbox. My requirement is like whether is place can be traveled by

1. Flight
2. Train
3. Bus
4. Ship

One can select all the four above options. For that I added a new field `Travel Details` , field type `Boolean` , Widget `Check boxes/radio buttons` . From [Drupal CCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855981/checkbox-for-drupal-cck)this reference 
I made `Number of values` equal to `4` . But I am getting only two fields, also without their names ! How can I able to make this content type to behave like normal HTML checkboxes with their names ?

Answer (score 0):

Could your problem be that you chose type Boolean which probably only has two values, 0 and 1?

In Drupal 6 (and possibly 7) you can test this by choosing type Integer (or Text) instead. You will also need to fill in the *"allowed values"* section for the new field. For Drupal 6 you enter this in the following format:

```
1|Label for 1
2|Label for 2
3|Label for 3
4|Label for 4
```

In this case you will be presented with 4 options called "Label for N". The value that they will return is selected will range from 1 to 4.